# MVC - Use something else than autofac to configure?

Tags: openiddict

I would love to use openiddict but I can't really use Autofac since my MVC project is using another IoC right now. Also, I'd love to be able to configure it with something else, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the doc and found how to not use autofac, but anyway I added it in autofac even if I already had another ioc